# Binding TreeView (again, yep) to List of my class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

So, in a few words. I have a structure of classes, each contains `List` with "child" items of another class. I need to bind it to the TreeView with custom Template for every class.

The main class looks like this plus some properties and metods:

```
  public static class TreeVM
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static List<ConfigVM> configsVM = new List<ConfigVM>();
  }
```

This contains a List of `ConfigVM` items:

```
  public class ConfigVM
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ComPortVM> comPortsVM = new List<ComPortVM>();
  }
```

The same with class `ComPortVM`, etc.

I need to display it with TreeView. I wrote some xaml-code to define the view of each class:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TreeVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding configsVM}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Height="16" GroupName="Config" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Image Source="Icons/IconConfig.png"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConfigVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding _comPortsVM}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Image Source="Icons/IconComPort.png"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And TreeView:

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridForTreeView" DataContext="{Binding vm:TreeVM}">
      <TreeView x:Name="ComPortsTree"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
```

But it doesn't work.

How to make it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
 public static List<ConfigVM> configsVM = new List<ConfigVM>();
```

for

```
 public List<ConfigVM> configsVM {get;set}
```

Then initialize your list in the contructor

```
public TreeVM (){ configsVM = new List<ConfigVM> ();}
```

Do the same for the other class.

Then in your XAML try to do this:

```
 <Grid x:Name="GridForTreeView" DataContext="{Binding vm:TreeVM}">
      <TreeView x:Name="ComPortsTree"
                ItemsSource="{Binding configsVM }" ItemTemplate= {StaticResource hierachTemplate} />
    </Grid>
```

and in your hierarchical:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="hierachTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding comPortsVM }">
```

Guess that's it...give it a try

Comment: Oh, I apologize for so looong reaction :D I put away my C# and xaml studies for a while and forgot about this question. However, your answer helped me a lot now, thank you!